# calculating multi squares in one textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on windows form application and I have homework to calculate the square of 5 numbers in one textbox and I have to put all 5 numbers in different lines

I expect the results to be like this,
you enter 5 numbers in each line

```
4
9
16
25
```

and get them in one single message box saying the results like

```
2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the Textbox Text into the function and It will Print all the SqureRoot of the Numbers

```
 private void squreRootFinder(string textBox)
    {
        string[] numbers = textBox.Split('\n');
        string data = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            data += Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i])) + " ";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(data);
    }
```

Comment: we have to do it with For() only

Comment: i have Modified it you can check it now. Accept It as Answer if It Works